# Using ESRI Query Layer to query OSM data in PostGIS database connection?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, openstreetmap, query-layer, other-tags

I have managed to connect to my OSM data using database connections in ArcGIS Desktop.  I have the OSM line, point, polygon and roads tables.  Now I am trying to query the tables using the Add New Query Layer.

I can load all data into ArcMap, but I would like to query the OSM tags.  The column tags is currently a Unknown type.  Therefore all my queries seems to fail.

Does anyone know how I should query the tags column here?

Comment: Please **edit** the question to include the CREATE TABLE syntax reported by PG Admin III.

Answer (score 1):

OSM tags are stored in an hstore column, a datatype not supported by ESRI.  If you know the tags your are looking for you can create a view or a new table converting that key->value pair into column values.  Here are some guides to help with that and to understand hstore better:

http://stormatics.com/howto-handle-key-value-data-in-postgresql-the-hstore-contrib/

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58279/attributes-from-an-hstore-column-as-separate-columns-in-a-view